# How to minimize rendering of page in CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

I just want to ask is there any technique available in CSS or HTML to minimize the rendering of a page to boost the performance of the page.

[image]

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://web.dev/content-visibility/)

Comment: Great, it's helpful :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have done it through CSS property (content-visibility)
look now the rendering time.[image: after applying]

This is the CSS property I used
[image: Css Property]